# Romeo & Juliet ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

One analytical model of the marriage relationship — Romeo & Juliet — includes the constant term before marriage (uninfluenced state), call it, $x_0$ for one spouse and $y_0$ for the other spouse. Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be the exponential rates of 'decay' for love or hate. One spouse may tend toward the uninfluenced state $x_0$ so the ODE is $\dot x = r_1 (x_0 - x)$ and $\dot y = r_1 (y_0 - y)$. Now add in the influence function $I(x)$ and $I(y)$ where $I(x) = a_1 y$ and $I(y) = a_2 x$. Therefore the coupled ODE is

$$ \begin{aligned} \dot x &= r_1 (x_0 - x) + a_1 y \\ \dot y &= r_2 (y_0 - y) + a_2 x \end{aligned} $$

How to solve this system of coupled linear ODEs?  1) Solve for $y$ in Eq (1) then sub into Eq. (2)??

Comment: Why not link to Strogatz's paper?

Comment: Google "matrix exponential". In short your system can be written in the linear form 
$$\dot{\boldsymbol x}=\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol x+\boldsymbol b$$
Which is a linear equation hence can be solved using exponentials.

Answer (score 1):

First, that system of equations IS linear.

I would start by differentiating each equation again:
$x''= -r_1x'+ a_1y'$
$y''= -r_1y'+ a_2x'$

Replace the $y'$ in the first equation by $y'= r_2(y_0- y)+ a_2x$:
$x''= -r_1x'+ a_1(r_2(y_0- y)+ a_2x)= (a_1a_2- r_1)x- a_1r_2y_0+ a_1r_2y$

Finally replace that remaining y with $(x'+ r_1x)/a_1$:
$x''= (a_1a_2- r_1)x- a_1r_2y_0+ r_2x'+ r_1r_2x$

So that we have the single linear differential equation in x with constant coefficients:

$x''- r_2x'- (r_1r_2+ a_1a_2- r_1)x= a_1r_2y_0$.